# Check each argument exists as an input in a function

Tags: r

I am trying to make a function which gets few inputs. I would like to know how to check the availability of my arguments . Here is my function:

```
MyFunction<-function(data,window,dim,option) {

}
```

First, I want to see if there is any argument , if no, print an error 
is it correct to use

```
if ~nargin
    error('no input data')
   }
```

Then, I want to make sure that the second argument is also inserted
is it right to ask like this

```
if nargin < 2
    error('no window size specified')
   }
```

Then, I want to check if the third argument is empty , set it as 1

```
if nargin < 3 || isempty(dim)
    dim<-1
   }
```

Comment: check out `?missing` (and for the third argument, set a default value of `dim=1` in the function definition)

Answer (score 3):

you can use `hasArg()`

```
testfunction <- function(x,y){
  if(!hasArg(x)){
    stop("missing x")
  }
  if(!hasArg(y)){
    y = 3
  } 
  return(x+y)
}

>testfunction(y=2)
Error in testfunction(y = 2) : missing x

> testfunction(x=1,y=2)
[1] 3

> testfunction(x=1)
[1] 4
```

Comment: can you extend your answer to few more stuff, I added more things above, would be great if you could add those in your answer.

Comment: You should be able to use the examples I already have to what you need, `hasArg` is simply a true/false for if that argument exists. Whatever logic you want to set up around it can then be supplied with logic operations `&` and `|`. If you are struggling to implement this could you show some updated attempt.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ben Bolker said , missing is used to test whether a value was specified as an argument to a function. You can have different conditions in your R functions such as warning or stop.
In your case, I would do the following

```
MyFunction<-function(data,window,dim,option) {
if (missing(data))
        stop("the first argument called data is missing")
if (missing(window))
        stop("the second argument called window is missing")
if (missing(dim))
        dim <- 1
if (missing(option))
        stop("the second argument called option is missing")
}
```